# How do I access 'activity' - the symbol won't resolve

Tags: android

I've just added a new activity to my Android Studio project in order to move app permissions checking into its own activity.

The activity screen shows an explanation of which permissions the app requires and why with a 'continue' button at the bottom for the user to click when they are ready to accept the permissions (or refuse them if they so wish)

I have added the function `clickRequestPermissions` to the button and have added the following code to have Android request the permissions, but I am getting an error that `activity` cannot be resolved.

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

The full code for this activity is very simple, so I've included it here as I believe the problem may be where I am trying to use the above snippet - somewhere that `activity` is not known or not available.

```
package com.myApp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class permissionsCheckAndSet extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_permissions_check_and_set);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void clickRequestPermissions(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request permissions now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        doRequestPermissions();

    }

    public void doRequestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "this" or getApplicationContext() instead of "activity" :

```
public void doRequestPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

}
```

Comment: Arrgghhh... I don't think I'm ever going to get used to when and when not to use `this` in Java...

Comment: @Fat Monk, You will get understand it eventually, for now you can use getApplicationContext() to overcome this problem.